# Identify antenna connector type

Tags: identification, connector

Is any one able to identify the type of connector shown below?

It is for the FM antenna on a Sony HiFi, model CMT-SBT20. The pitch is 2.5mm, only one crimp is fitted. I've seen the assembly shown below can be purchased on eBay/Amazon etc but I'm really after the connector details.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My [Identiconn Connector Identification Utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=lo_prof_1r_w2b_conn_2p5&s=XH%20(2.5m)) identifies that as a [JST XHP-2](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/XHP-2/555485). (Or a knock-off by some other company.)

[image: JST XHP-2]

{Digikey}

Comment: This tool is amazing! It now has a home in my utilities bookmark folder.

Comment: I am pleased, thank you.

Comment: Yes the XHP looks to be spot on. Nice link too, thanks